# Telerik.Web.UI.RecurrenceRule.TryParse() equivalent in Kendo UI MVC Scheduler control?

Tags: c#, telerik, kendo-ui

So as as the title states, im looking for the equivalent of the `Telerik.Web.UI.RecurrenceRule.TryParse()` in kendo ui mvc.

I need to enumerate the occations in a rule to see perform various business logic.

I also have a support ticket in the kendo ui forums up: [Link to kendo forums](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/scheduler/telerik-web-ui-recurrencerule-tryparse%28%29-in-kendo-ui-mvc-.aspx#boJgpK6aG2OF1P8AAFTdxQ)

Any help beyond having to import the `Telerik.Web.UI` library would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Kendo support.

> I'm afraid that neither is supported by the KendoUI Scheduler widget.
>   As you may be aware the recurrence rules are expanded on the client thus such server side method is not available.
>   The order in which the events are rendered cannot be changed too.